# Getting "Unpermitted parameter: address" even though I included field in my "permit" statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, controller, belongs-to

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this in my user_controller.rb …

```
  def update
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to url_for(:controller => 'races', :action => 'index') and return
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :dob, :address, :automatic_import)
    end
```

and when my parameters get submitted to “update,”

```
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bz24jRzK5qVWolW0oBoQbniiaQi96MeFFmzNjB4kCr0ifUYSsitvQIyod5AWDJd4KS3lrt3mzLiG8F9ef3aJkg==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Anthony", "last_name"=>"Alvarado", "dob(2i)"=>"1", "dob(3i)"=>"14", "dob(1i)"=>"1908", "address"=>{"city"=>"chicago"}, "automatic_import"=>"0"}, "state"=>"CT", "country"=>{"country"=>"233"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"13"}
Unpermitted parameter: address
```

Why am I getting this unpermitted parameter message when it is included in my “require” statement above?  I even have this in my app/models/user.rb file …

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  …
  belongs_to :address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues that are linked. (My assumption is that the user has one address, and not that the address has one user.) The model relationship should be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  …
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

The address model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  …
  belongs_to :user
```

This should eliminate the unpermitted parameter error for address.

Comment: I tried your sugegstion but still got the same error.  However, I don't htink you're right about the belongs_to and has_one.  the uses table has an address_id column that is a foreign key back to the address table.  The rails documentation, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, says the table that is referenced by the foreign key shoudl have the "has_one" designation.  Am I wrong?

Comment: If you have a user with an address then the the user has_one address and the address belongs_to the user. That's the model. Foreign keys, etc  is not point -- it's the parent/child relationship has to be defined properly first before anything in the MVC will work.. Good luck!

Comment: Just for kicks, I tried switching the has_one and belongs_to per your suggestion, but I still get teh error.  Anyway, I included that link in my comments -- if table A has a foreign key to table B, the model A, per the documentation, must have a "belongs_to" in Rails.  I think it sucks too but those are the rules!  Let me know if the documentation is wrong.

Comment: You have a data modeling problem; not a rules problem. Good luck on your journey.

Comment: Let me ask you this -- in the database that backs the code you displayed above, do you have a column named "user.address_id" or "address.user_id" ?

Comment: In the has_one/belongs_to data model above, Address has a column 'user_id'; There's an index defined in the schema as 'add_index "address, ["user_id"], name: "index_address_on_user_id", using: :btree'

Comment: Ok thanks for that clarification.  So now picture the opposite scenario where I have a user with an address_id field.  How do the correspodning models look then?  That is essentially teh question I'm trying to answer, hoping that leads to figuring out all this "Unpermitted parameter: address" nonsense.

Comment: Your controller code is written as if the user is the parent of the address record. But your address_id comment above indicates  that your database is defined the opposite, with the address being the parent of the user. You can't make this work. This is a data model problem.

Comment: I'm sure my code is wrong, which is why I'm asking the question.  The given is that there is a "user.address_id" column in the database.  I have a form in which I collect the user's name and address (which consist of a city, state, and country field).  If the controller code is wrong, what is the right contorller code to make it work?

Comment: Your data model does not seem logically correct. The problem is not the controller. Does a user have an address?

Comment: Sure a user has an address.  My address is 846 W Montrose, Chicago, IL 60613.  Drop by some time and we'll have a beer.  I also have other entities in my system (e.g. events) that have addresses.  By the logic you have listed, I should ahve a column in my address table for each entity that has an address, even if that column isn't used.  So I would have "address.user_id," "address.event_id," etc.  That seems really wasteful to me.  What I'm asking (having "user.address_id", "event.address_id", "something_else.address_id") seems pretty normal.

Comment: Good one! Good luck to you in your journey!